# Does Papertrail support MySQL native json column?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

I've read the docs and it says it supports PostgreSQL, but I couldn't find anything about MySQL:

https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail/blob/v11.1.0/README.md#postgresql-json-column-type-support

Since Rails 5 we have support for MySQL JSON type too:
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/21227

Does PaperTrail support MySQL the same way as it does with PostgreSQL?

Comment: Some PT features, like the `where_object` and `where_object_changes` methods construct their own SQL, using e.g. the `->>?` and `@>` operators. (Source: `lib/paper_trail/queries`) Does MySQL have those operators? If so, then the answer is probably "yes". Whatever you discover, if you want to improve the docs, I'd happily review a PR.